# Why do we recycle table view cells in iOS or Domain Objects in html?

Tags: javascript, ios

When I write iOS application, the way I get a new table view cell is to recycle the previously disappeared cell and repopulate it. Similarly, when I implement infinite scroll in javascript, I recycle the top object and repopulate the bottom. What's the reasoning behind that? Why can't I just remove the old one and insert? What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: Allocating and deallocating an object takes time. Having spent time allocating an object it is wasteful to de allocate it when it moves off screen only to have to allocate a new object for the cell that is moving onscreen.